# Mean of Two Columns Filtered

Tags: dataframe, join, group-by, concatenation, mean

df contains three columns: percent, opponent1, opponent2. I want the mean percentage of playing every opponent who was played more than 1 time. Same opponent may appear in either `opponent1` or `opponent2` columns.

I have a solution but it seems clumsy. What is a more proper solution? In particular `concat` method seems ill-used.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(.3,'Andy','Bob'),(.45,'Bob','Cathy'),(.5,'Cathy','Doug'),(.9,'Bob','Cathy')],columns=['Pct','Opponent1','Opponent2'])
```

|  | Pct | Opponent1 | Opponent2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.3 | Andy | Bob |
| 1 | 0.45 | Bob | Cathy |
| 2 | 0.5 | Cathy | Doug |
| 3 | 0.9 | Bob | Cathy |

```
df2 = pd.concat([df,df])
df2['Opponent'] = df['Opponent1'].tolist()+df['Opponent2'].tolist()
df3 = df2.groupby('Opponent').agg({'Pct': ['mean','size']})
df4 = df3[df3['Pct','size'].gt(1)]
df5 = df4.sort_values([('Pct', 'mean')],ascending=False)
```

Correct Result df5:

| Opponent | ('Pct', 'mean') | ('Pct', 'size') |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cathy | 0.616667 | 3 |
| Bob | 0.55 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
df = pd.concat([df,df]).assign(Opponent = df['Opponent1'].tolist()+df['Opponent2'].tolist()).groupby('Opponent').agg({'Pct': ['mean','size']}).loc[lambda x: x['Pct','size'].gt(1)].sort_values([('Pct', 'mean')],ascending=False)
```

or an easier to read two liner:

```
df = pd.concat([df,df]).assign(Opponent = df['Opponent1'].tolist()+df['Opponent2'].tolist())
df = df.groupby('Opponent').agg({'Pct': ['mean','size']}).loc[lambda x: x['Pct','size'].gt(1)].sort_values([('Pct', 'mean')],ascending=False)
```